# Build simple indoor postioning with ibeacon

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

I'm trying to build indoor positioning system for Android, depends on ibeacons to detect where am i, how i can go to other room.

let's take an example:
in my home i want to put one beacon in every-room, in my application i have a simple indoor map that show my home design contains fixed point for every-beacon and fixed path between them.

how can i make my phone moving inside that map depends on the distance between my phone and the beacon and make the phone movement over the fixed path.

is their any solution without using gps or any LonLat point?
if their any better idea that can helps?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is map your beacons to an arbitrary coordinate space, irrespective of GPS. You could map GPS to it as well, but I think you'll get very little out of it until the the distances between the beacons are significantly larger than your average GPS accuracy - in other words, until your mapped area is very large, which won't happen if you're talking about a small indoor environment.

And even if you could achieve "perfect" GPS accuracy in your environment, on a phone that will be limited to a max accuracy of a 5m radius which *still* isn't guaranteed (GPS errors are assumed to follow a normal distribution where the reported accuracy is only as good as 68% confident, or 1 standard deviation from the mean.)  So if GPS is your input for positioning, you have to accept the degree of error with that input.

With your mapped coordinate space, you could get the estimated distance from your beacons based on the signal strength and then perform triangulation to get an approximate point. You need 3+ beacons at any given time for this to work.  One naive approach might be to pick 3 beacons from the scanned beacon list with the best RSSI values, and triangulate from those.

The problem with this approach is, again, interference and accuracy, which are linked. When you're moving within your home, the walls will dampen the signal and other radio electronics may impact it as well.

Answer (score 0):

A simple beacon-based approach is to lay out beacons on a grid (or just in each room), then range for beacons in the app, and determine which one you are closest to.  You then plot a blue dot on an X,Y point on the map based on a lookup table of beacon to X,Y.

For a small demo, it's pretty simple.  For a large scale installation and bells and whistles, it becomes pretty complex.  You can read how we did it at the Consumer Electronics Show in my blog post here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/01/13/beacon-navigation-at-the-consumer-electronics-show.html

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach of "computing the distance from the beacon, based on RSSI reading" won't work for a number of reasons.  Say that there is (and there is) a formula for theoretically mapping an RSSI to a distance.  So let's say that distance(i) = f(RSSI(i)) for the beacon i.  In practice the signal sill be received (indoors) via multiple paths and, due to the different distances the signal travels to your device, it will display a quite a bit of variability.  These multi path effects will, furthermore, be position dependent.  You will not be able to use multilateration effectively in that scenario.  Furthermore RSSI will depend from what kind of receiving antenna you have (= device), which in case of android can be a challenge to manage, due to the large number of phone models available.

In short you should do some research on fingerprinting techniques for indoor location, there is a vast literature out there.  To better understand the basic idea take a look at this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hITAQ6yPZ3I

In short, you should read the "array of bluetooth (or wi-fi) signals" RSSIs in the environment, and compare such array with a previously collected database of "arrays". When you collect samples for your database, you will have to do it in a grid of points, each one associated with an X and Y position on your map or blueprint. It is not that different from the approach of seeking the closes beacon, but it is a lot more general, can be more precise and requires (usually) fewer beacons (although not always). The accuracy might not go below 2-3 meters according if you have too few beacons and are too far apart.

NOTE: Unfortunately the code underpinning the app in the video above is iOS, so not relevant to post source code here. Take it as an example of the general idea.